# I'm not sure why my click event won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I'm trying to add a click event to .user that will change the background color of the entire page to green. I'm very new to jQuery, but the code looks right to me. When I click the .users button, nothing happens. Anyone have any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $body = $('body')
  /*$body.html('');*/

  //  var currentView = "Twittler Feed"
  var currentView = $('<p>Twittler Feed</p>');
  var refreshTweet = function() {
    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    var endInd = index - 10;
    while (index >= endInd) {
      var tweet = streams.home[index];
      var $tweet = $('<div class="tweets"><p class="posted-by"><button class="user">@' +
        tweet.user + '</button><p class="message">' + tweet.message +
        '</p><p class="time">' + /*$.timeago(tweet.created_at)*/ tweet.created_at + '</p></div>');
      currentView.appendTo('#sidebar')
      $tweet.appendTo($body);
      index -= 1;
    }
  }

  refreshTweet();

  $('.refresh').on('click', function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('tweets')) {
      $('.tweets').remove();
    }
    var result = refreshTweet();
    $body.prepend(result);
  })

  $('.user').on('click', 'button', function() {
    currentView = this.user
    $('body').css('background-color', 'green');

  });
});
```

Comment: I guess you are not supposed to break your code here: `var $tweet =` and your JS is screwed up here. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: console say anything?

Comment: `if (document.getElementsByClassName('tweets')) {
      $('.tweets').remove();
    }` just call remove, why make multiple calls.

Comment: The this.user makes no sense since the element you are referencing has no user property. Do you want to select the text of the element with the class user?

Comment: You are not [delegating](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the event corretly: the element `button` itself has the class `.user`. But the event should be binded to an element which already exist on page load

Comment: See here for duplicate (I linked wrong duplicate first time) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: In summary, use event delegation:  `$(document).on('click', '.refresh', function() ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)